# SetWindowText show Unrecognizable Code from InternetReadFile()

Tags: c, utf-8, utf-16, winapi

i want to convert an utf-8 encoded web page source code downloaded using InternetReadFile to utf-16 which windows can recognize.

here is the code snippet:

```
HINTERNET hConnect,hSession;
char *szBuffer = malloc(WEBSOURCE_SIZE);
wchar_t *wszBuffer = (wchar_t *)malloc(WEBSOURCE_SIZE);
TCHAR szStr[100];
DWORD dwSize=0;
DWORD dwDownloaded;
if(szBuffer == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(hwndGetBtn,TEXT("error"),TEXT("Error"),MB_ICONHAND);
}
GetWindowText(hwndUrlEdt,szStr,sizeof(szStr)/sizeof(TCHAR));
hSession = InternetOpen(TEXT("testWinINet"), PRE_CONFIG_INTERNET_ACCESS, NULL, INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER, 0);
hConnect = InternetOpenUrl(hSession,szStr,NULL,0,INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE,0);
ZeroMemory(szBuffer,WEBSOURCE_SIZE);
while (InternetReadFile(hConnect,szBuffer,WEBSOURCE_SIZE,&dwDownloaded))
{
    if (0==dwDownloaded) break;
    szBuffer[dwDownloaded]=0;
}
len=MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,szBuffer,-1,NULL,0);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,szBuffer,-1,wszBuffer,sizeof(wszBuffer));

SetWindowText(hwndShowEdt,wszBuffer);
```

hwndShowEdt editbox always show Unrecognizable Code while the web page is utf-8 encoded.

so can anyone find the mistake of my code?

Comment: sizeof(wszBuffer) is wrong.  The loop doesn't make sense, you only store the last chunk.  No sign of you using *len*.

Comment: @hans-passant  `len` is unused, how do i modified the code and make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the charset of the web page can only be recognized by HTML **meta** tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=gb2312">
```